# Firebase hosting won't register Polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting

I have an app scaffold created with:

```
polymer init
```

with a polymer.json file that looks like

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app.html"
}
```

then:

```
firebase init
```

With a firebase.json that looks like:

```
{
  "database": {
  "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/bundled",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If i run `polymer build` on the initial app structure generated by `polymer init` and then push to hosting with `firebase deploy` I get these errors (in the JS console) when trying to open the site on Firebase hosting:

```
webcomponents-lite.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
webcomponents-lite.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
my-app.html:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
```

for reference, here are `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Snappy Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="/src/my-app/my-app.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `my-app.html`:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]</h2>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: 'my-app',
         },
       },
     });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

both of these files are created auto-magically via `polymer init`

Note: Even if I serve the non-build code through Firebase Hosting, the errors remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a higher chance that the problem arises from the `webcomponentsjs` polyfill. Check to make sure that the `webcomponentsjs` polyfill can be found from your `build` directory. It must be missing or you forgot to include it inside your `polymer.json` if you're using `polymer-cli`.

Comment: Adding webcomponentsjs to the includeDependencies attribute in polymer.json cleared the errors up. Thanks for the tip!